# Have problem installing CUDNN on WSL due to GPG key absence

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cudnn

I was trying to install CUDNN on WSL(Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS) by methods in [this nvidia page](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#installlinux-deb).
I have tried the debain local installation, the debain package I install is downloaded from [this nvidia page](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download#a-collapse850-116).  However, the installation failed because the public CUDA GPG key does not appear to be installed.

```
sh@SH-PC:~$ sudo dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.0.96_1.0-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 69187 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.0.96_1.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.0.96 (1.0-1) over (1.0-1) ...
Setting up cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.0.96 (1.0-1) ...

The public CUDA GPG key does not appear to be installed.
To install the key, run this command:
sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.0.96/cudnn-local-0579404E-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
```

Of course I also tried `sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.0.96/cudnn-local-0579404E-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/` , but this did not help either.

Also, I am not sure what is GPG key doing in this installation.

Please help me get throught the GPG key problem.

P.S. The CUDA version I installed is 11.7, though I do not know if this matter.